# Asp.net menu selected item

Tags: asp.net

I've been struggling with this asp.net Menu control problem for days and it's driving me crazy. Here the code:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="hrMainMenu" DynamicHorizontalOffset="1" >
    <DynamicHoverStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle ForeColor="White" />
    <DynamicMenuStyle Width="97px" HorizontalPadding="1px" />
    <DynamicSelectedStyle ForeColor="White" />
    <DynamicItemTemplate>
        <div class="dinamicMenuItemTemplate">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' EnableTheming="True"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </DynamicItemTemplate>
    <StaticMenuItemStyle ForeColor="White" CssClass="StaticMenuItemStyle" />
    <StaticMenuStyle HorizontalPadding="10px" CssClass="StaticMenuStyle" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="staticMenuItemTemplateSelected" ForeColor="Red" />
        <StaticItemTemplate>
            <div class="staticMenuItemTemplate">
                <div class="innerMenuElement">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                </div>
        </StaticItemTemplate>
    </asp:Menu>
```

Now this is my css:

```
.staticMenuItemTemplate 
{
    background-position: left;
    background-image: url('../../images/mainLayout/menuDefault.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.staticMenuItemTemplate:hover
{
    background-image: url('../../images/mainLayout/menuHover.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.staticMenuItemTemplateSelected
{
    background-image: url('../../images/mainLayout/menuSelected.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: left !important;
    color: #FF00FF !important;
}
```

I want to display a different image when the menu item has been selected (menuSelected.png) but whilst the class `staticMenuItemTemplate:hover` seems to work and indeed the image changes, the class `staticMenuItemTemplateSelected` doesn't. Only the text gets pink as stated but the image won't change.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the `staticMenuItemTemplateSelected` class is being applied to your selected item (check source of HTML output)?  Also, are you SURE that selected image exists in that path?  Will it come up in the browser if you put that path in the address bar?

Comment: What happens when you change `.staticMenuItemTemplateSelected` to `.staticMenuItemTemplate:active`? Or when you specify these changes in the `StaticSelectedStyle` property rather than the CSS class itself?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this was a copy/paste error, but you're missing a `</div>` tag in your `StaticItemTemplate`. I can't imagine that's the cause of your problems, but nonetheless.

Comment: to Shawn Steward, staticMenuItemTemplateSelected class is being applied because the font color changes from red to pink correctly and the selected images does exist in my path because it shows up in browser. To jwiscarson, when I changed to :active or :focus or :link it didn't work because the selected image showed up only when it was being clicked and disappeared afterward. All divs have been closed correctly. Thanks for your concern anyway.

Comment: In StaticSelectedStyle I've set the font fore color to red just to see if I could override it, and it turns in fact to pink.

Comment: Do you, by chance, have a live example up somewhere where others could check out the problem directly?

Comment: unfortunately I haven't any live example to show you, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem has to do with how the HTML renders for this control.  In my tests, I end up with something like:

```
<td>
  <a class="... staticMenuItemTemplateSelected ..." ...>
    <div class="staticMenuItemTemplate">
      <span>Menu text here</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</td>
```

So you can see that the `<a>` tag is getting the staticMenuItemTemplateSelected applied, but the inner `<div>` is getting the staticMenuItemTemplate class which ends up overriding the staticMenuItemTemplateSelected style since it is more specific.

If you change your declaration of .staticMenuItemTemplateSelected to

```
.staticMenuItemTemplateSelected .staticMenuItemTemplate
{
    background-image: url('../../images/mainLayout/menuSelected.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: left !important;
    color: #FF00FF !important;
}
```

you will make that style more specific than the style for .staticMenuItemTemplate and it should work.

[FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) with FireFox is a great tool for investigating CSS weirdness issues.